# Android system buttons are overlapping ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-tabbed-activity

I have main activity with tabbed fragments .. in fragment I have listview, but when I scroll to last item on bottom, this item is covered by system buttons:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CofoH.png)

here is my activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.martin.fitnessapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and here is my current tab xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
    <!--tools:context="com.example.martin.fitnessapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">-->

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listViewMuscleGroups"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

For each fragment i have created separated class which extend Fragment class. If you need I can add this class too, but I think doesn't matter about that.

Comment: don't delete this post , this seems like a bug and this shouldn't suppose to happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:layout_alignParentStart="true"` is left (or right depending if you're in RTL languages), you probably also want `alignParentTop` in that ListView.The listview probably wants a `match_parent` width as well.

Anyway, I'm not sure what's going on, but I'd play with moving  `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the RelativeLayout that contains the ListView, because that's what causing the ViewPager's fragment content to be drawn like so.

For the record, I don't have much coordinator layout experience.

Comment: thanks for response ... I found solution with whis command : android:layout_marginBottom="?android:attr/actionBarSize"

Comment: yeah, well I was going to say, the other option is to add margin at the bottom (on iOS we add "insets") which is essentially padding on Android :)